# Web View not loading full content from a web page?

Tags: android, dictionary, webview

I am working on android application . There is web view used. i am showing a url content in web view . in web page there are some text and a  map. text are showing in it .It is not loading map. what can i do that it load map also in web view.

Comment: What's the address you're loading into this `WebView` ?

Comment: i am showing google map in it.

Comment: One quick hint - do you have `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: And also, paste the code for the `WebView` loading and creation. Thanks

Comment: Also - do you have `android.permission.INTERNET` in the `AndroidManifest` ?

Comment: Did something from the above methods fix the problem? If yes, which one, so I can add it as an Answer?

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);? this one was help ful for me.

Comment: Well, if you figured out the fix, then paste an Answer and aceept it, so that if somebody sees this and has the same problem, he/she can have the solution right away:) If the code above fixed the issue - I will paste the Asnwer.